# SCP Permission denied (publickey). on EC2 only when using -r flag on directories

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2, file-permissions, scp

`scp -r /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/keypairfile.pem uploads ec2-user@publicdns:/var/www/html`

where uploads is a directory returns  Permission denied (publickey).

However

`scp -i /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/keypairfile.pem footer.php ec2-user@publicdns:/var/www/html`

works **(notice the flag change).**

uploads is an empty folder

These are the file permissions for the uploads directory

`drwxrwxrwx   3 geoffreysangston  admin     102 Nov 15 01:40 uploads`

These are the file permissions for /var/www/html

`drwxr-x--- 2 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jan  5 20:45 html`

I've tried changing html to 777 and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

The `-i` flag specifies the private key (.pem file) to use. If you don't specify that flag (as in your first command) it will use your default ssh key (usually under `~/.ssh/`).

So in your first command, you are actually asking `scp` to upload the .pem file itself using your default ssh key. I don't think that is what you want.

Try instead with:

```
scp -r -i /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/keypairfile.pem uploads/* ec2-user@publicdns:/var/www/html/uploads
```

Comment: This now gives me "scp: /var/www/html/uploads: Permission denied" so I think I'm getting somewhere. It probably now has to do with the file permissions so I'll mess around with them some more. Thank you.

I started learning about working with unix / the console just a little while ago with a jump in approach. How would you say is the best way at going about it or is it really just a learn by doing deal? Thanks.

Comment: Your permissions seem ok. I think the problem is with the target directory. I've edited the command in my answer (2 changes), you can try with that. As for how to learn unix/linux, I prefer "learn by doing", but it depends on people. Reading a few tutorials on the Web cannot hurt.

Comment: Since this was the top answer when I had a similar problem (on an RPi), I'll just add that in my case I ran it with the debug flag `vvv` and noticed that scp was trying `/root/.ssh/id_rsa` and failing. I simply added `-i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa` so that it was pointing to the correct user's keyfile and it worked. Debug output is almost always useful.

Answer (score 46):

Even if above solutions don't work, check permissions to destination file of aws ec2 instance. May be you can try with- `sudo chmod 777 -R destinationFolder/*`

Comment: Wordpress codex suggests 755 or 750. But 777 will do fine as well. https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: what if someone's destinationFolder is home ? it's not good way to give permission to home

Comment: @Beyhan Yes, I agree. Typically you copy your content to a public directory then move it to appropriate directory.

Comment: Do sudo chmod 777 -R folder/file_you_want_to_copy.whatever_extension.   I did "sudo chmod 777 -R ~/" in my ec2 instance instead and ended up getting "permission denied (publickey gssapi-keyex gssapi-with-mic)" every time i tried to ssh back into my ec2 instance. I had to use the aws managment console to connect to my instance again and then did "sudo chmod 750 -R ~/" so I could ssh back into my ec2 instance again without the "permission denied(publickkey...) error above.

Answer (score 24):

transferring file from local to remote host

scp -i (path of your key) (path for your file to be transferred)   (username@ip):(path where file to be copied)

```
e.g scp -i aws.pem /home/user1/Desktop/testFile   ec2-user@someipAddress:/home/ec2-user/
```

P.S. - ec2-user@someipAddress of this ip address should have access to the destination folder in my case /home/ec2-user/

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize I had to use the -i flag in combination with the pem file and then my source file followed by destination.

Comment: This worked for me. I use the -i flag to access the instance so not sure why I didn't realize I would still need to use the -i flag with key to access the instance in order to move files. Thanks

Comment: what should I do if I want to transfer a directory from a remote host to local?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload the file `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/keypairfile.pem` to `ec2-user@publicdns:/var/www/html`, you can simply do:

> `scp -Cr /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/keypairfile.pem/uploads/ ec2-user@publicdns:/var/www/html/`

Where:

- `-C` - Compress data
- `-r` - Recursive

Comment: The path to uploads is /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/projectname/uploads I was just using "uploads" cause I was calling it from inside the projectname directory

I tried scp -Cr /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/keypairfile.pem /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/projectname/uploads/ ec2-user@ec2-54-200-81-203.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/var/www/html/

that also didn't work

Answer (score 2):

answer for newbies (like me):

I had this error when trying to copy the files while being on the server.

So my answer is: **exit**, or open another terminal